# How to identify if popup download of Adobe flash Player was infact a virus or malicious on?

Tags: adobe-flash

How to identify if popup download of Adobe flash Player was in fact a virus or malicious on El Capitan, OS x10.11.6?
I am not a savvy person but I can do things if someone explains it to me in plain English.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Without a screen shot of what the pop-up in question looks like it will be impossible to tell. You may need to edit your question to instead ask for steps to take in finding any possible malware this suspected thing installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically went to Adobe & downloaded it right from their page at https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ then assume it was malicious & discard it.

If it arrived in the form of a Disk Image (.dmg) then so long as you don't mount the image, the file itself is inert & can safely be trashed.
If it was a Windows executable (.exe) then that is also technically safe on a Mac - ie, it will not run - so can also be safely discarded.
If it was a compressed file (.zip, .7z, gz etc) then so long as it remains unextracted, again it is safe to simply discard.

If it was anything other than one of those types, or if you extracted any archive, then scan your computer with something like [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com) or send the file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload) for further analysis.

Comment: I want to acknowledge and thank you, Tetsujin, so very much for such a concise and easily understood answer!